# sending tensorflow job to remote GPU

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am a systems researcher (student) and I'm new to tensorflow.

My setup is as follows -
I have 2 GPUs say X and Y. Both are CUDA capable. I have a Ubuntu VM on GPU-X (not cuda capable, no GPU passthrough)
The VM, X and Y are all on the same LAN and reachable.

Problem - I know that I can install tensorflow on my VM and it will know that cudatoolkit and NVidia driver are absent and run its job using the CPU but what if I wanted to use GPU X or Y to run the tensorflow job ? is there a provision in tensorflow to make this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be made possible first with the help of a **Hypervisor** and then TensorFlow can use it once configured. Popular hypervisors include **Microsoft Hyper-V, VMware ESXi, Citrix XenServer, etc**.

The **VM** should first have **GPU support enabled** while configuring it.

There are 2 ways by which the VM can use the host's GPU capabilities.

1. **With a GPU pass-through**

   - A pass-through mode provides access, control and use of an entire device.
   - When a GPU operates in pass-through mode, the hypervisor assigns one GPU to one VM.
   - Hence even if the GPU has multiple cores, all of them would be assigned to one and only one VM. Other VMs will not be able to access it.
   - Nevertheless, modern graphics adapters often support multiple GPU chips, and each GPU chip can be assigned to different VMs.
   - This technique is sometimes referred to as virtual dedicated graphics acceleration (vDGA)
   - Pass-through mode is ideal for centrally hosted VMs that run the most demanding or graphics-intensive applications.
   - Microsoft Hyper-V, Citrix XenServer and VMware ESXi all support pass-through mode.
2. **Using vGPU**

   - This approach creates a time-sharing environment that enables multiple VMs to share the GPU's resources. For example, if a GPU is virtualized into 10 vGPUs, and each vGPU is assigned to one of 10 VMs, each VM would have access to the GPU(and its CUDA cores) for 10% of the time. This technique is sometimes referred to as virtual shared graphics acceleration, or vSGA.
     [image]

- Hyper-V does not yet support vGPU at time of publication, but Citrix
  XenServer and VMware ESXi can run a virtual GPU manager.

The complete reference guide for making this happen can be found [here](https://www.techtarget.com/searchitoperations/tip/Assign-GPUs-to-virtual-machines-with-VMware-vGPU-mode#:%7E:text=Hypervisors%20support%20GPUs%20in%20either,can%20use%20those%20GPU%20capabilities.)

You can also refer to this [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZtuiLYnb_g)